# How to disable mailed output for an at job?

Tags: linux, at

I'd like to disable `at` mail notifications for a certain class of jobs. For example, when testing the use case below (killing an at job midstream) I *don't* want output, but the same code in production I do want the mailed output:

```
$ at now <<<'/usr/bin/timeout 15s nc -l 20242'
job 71 at 2016-05-16 15:03
$ pidof /usr/bin/timeout
11853
$ kill 11853
$ mail
Heirloom Mail version 12.4 7/29/08.  Type ? for help.
"/var/spool/mail/bishop": 1 message 1 new
>N  1 bishop@trencher  Mon May 16 15:03  16/920   "Output from your job       71"
& 1
Message  1:
From bishop@trencher  Mon May 16 15:03:30 2016
Date: Mon, 16 May 2016 15:03:30 -0400
From: bishop@trencher
Subject: Output from your job       71
To: bishop@trencher
Status: R

/bin/bash: line 1: 11853 Terminated              /usr/bin/timeout 15s nc -l 20242
```

I know I can set `MAILPATH=/dev/null`, but I'd prefer to have more fine grained control. Setting `MAIL` and `MAILTO` have had no obvious effect. I thought I could edit the job to remove the `# mail` directive, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
at 15:15 <<<'date'
at -c 73 | grep -v '^# mail bishop' | at 15:15
atrm 73
```

I've searched high and low, but let's just say searching for a command named at is non-trivial. I can't even seem to find the at source code: isn't it in GNU coreutils?

**UPDATE**: Station identification:

```
$ uname -a
Linux trencher 4.4.8-20.46.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 27 19:28:52 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ at -V
at version 3.1.10
```

Is it possible to control, per job, whether the output -- any output -- is mailed to the submitting user?

Comment: What version of `at` do you have? The `-M      Never send mail to the user` bit in the manual for the one on RedHat 6 looks promising. Otherwise, you'll probably have to nix all stdout/stderr on the development boxes at jobs.

Comment: Can you give us more information about your OS Version/Distro, please?

Comment: @thrig Same thing in the manual on my Debian testing box. Suspect it's widespread and you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @thrig Regrettably, no `-M`. I have `-m` (small case "m"), but that's described as "Send mail to the user when the job has completed, even if there was no output."

Comment: @Grimdari `uname -a` added.

Comment: Looking at the source code for at 3.1.10, there is no -M option.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 Can you send the link to the at 3.1.10 source code? Maybe it's because I'm sick, but I just couldn't find it (even at GNU Savannah).

Comment: @bishop See SRPM link at http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/6.7/x86_64/Packages/at-3.1.10-48.el6.x86_64.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The RedHat (and thus Centos and friends) `at` and also Debian-derived vintages (as `rpm -qi at` on RedHat indicates a Debian URL, and also derobert in comments, above) should support a `-M` option:

```
    -M      Never send mail to the user.
```

Lacking this, another option would be to suppress output from the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec >/dev/null 2>&1
... the usual job commands here ...
```

Or, instead pipe the output to `logger` or to a log file in the event the output does need to be inspected.

Yet another option would be to alter the mail transport agent, especially since these are development systems, and to drop all mail to `/dev/null` or into a mailbox file somewhere on the development server, but that's more work.

Comment: In my test environment, I have a function that just wraps my command in a bash script with the stdout and stderr exec'd to dev null. Works well enough, though I'd love to have `-M` for its simplicity. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: So you never know if anything fails?

Comment: @Walf That would seem to be the point of the question, yes. Sometimes you really _don't_ care if a task succeeds or not, you just want it to make a best effort. If it fails, c'est la vie and don't bother me about it.

Answer (score 0):

Precede the command passed to `at` with `chronic` (from the `moreutils` package) so that you still get *both* stderr and stdout, if the command exited with an error status, otherwise nothing.

Do the same to your cron jobs while you're at it.